# How to solve problem to remote access to rabbitmq management console?

Tags: rabbitmq, remote-access

I'm new to rabbitmq and just installed two version of rabbitmq on two different devices.
the machines are located in the same network.
I am trying to open management console of one of them through the other one.
but the page does not open.
although i have already enabled the console plugin and i can access it from localhost.
what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to see the login page with the user and password prompt, check your firewall (port 15672). If you see the page but cannot login, the issue is that by default, the `guest` user can only connect from localhost